# Grails: Add items to list and attach it to its parent object

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a Recipe, Ingredient and RecipeIngredient domains as below:

```
class Ingredient {
    String title
}

class Recipe {

    String title
    String description

    static hasMany = [ingredients: RecipeIngredient]
}

class RecipeIngredient {

    Ingredient ingredient

    static belongsTo = [recipe: Recipe]

    Measure measure
    Double amount
}
```

In my recipe/Create.gsp page when I want to create a new recipe, I want to add its ingredients one by one and addto recipe instance and save them all together.

```
<g:form controller="recipe" action="save" method="POST">
    **/* HERE I WANT TO BE ABLE TO ADD ALL INGREDIENTS ONE BY ONE */
    <select value="${recipe_ingredient.ingredient}">
        <g:each in="${allIngredients}" status="i" var="ingredient">
            <option>${ingredient.title}</option>
        </g:each>
    </select>
    <select name="recipe_ingredient.measure" value="${recipe_ingredient.measure}">
        <g:each in="${enums.Measure.values()}" var="m">
            <option>${m}</option>
        </g:each>
    </select>
    <input name="recipe_ingredient.amount" placeholder="Measure" value="${recipe_ingredient.amount}" />
    <g:actionSubmit value="Add" action="addIngredient" />
    /* END */**

    <div class="row">
        <input name="title" value="${instance?.title}" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <input name="titleEng" value="${instance?.description}" placeholder="Description" />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <g:submitButton name="Create" />
    </div>
</g:form>
```

How can I achieve such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight-forward way would be:

```
<g:select name="rawIngredients" value="${recipe.ingredients*.ingredient*.id}"
  from="${allIngredients}" optionKey="id" optionValue="title" multiple="true"/>
```

Then in the controller:

```
def save() {
  Recipe recipe // bind or create somehow, e.g. via command-object

  recipe.ingredients?.clear()

  Ingredient.getAll( params.list( 'rawIngredients' ) ).each{ ing ->
    recipe.addToIngredients new RecipeIngredient( ingredient:ing, amount:1, ... )
  }

  recipe.save()
}
```

Comment: User must enter the amount, measure etc for each RecipeIngredient. How can I do that? They are textinputs, not just one select. It need to be added to ingredients list of recipe.

Comment: For instance, it select salt 1 teaspoon and add, then rice 2 cup and add, water 3 cup add
Then input for recipe and then save them all

Comment: In this case you gonna need some javascript front-end processing to react on "+" button click. You have to do it yourself, Grails doesn't support it out-of-box.

Comment: With javascript you can show some form (maybe in a popup) and collect it's data to JSON array or an array of hidden fields. You can also implement a small react* app to make the form filling easy and send the whole data as a JSON to the server